# I'm trying to filter the response from the below controller. I dont want the variables to be included in the search if they are empty

Tags: c#, linq, filter

I'm trying to filter the response from the below controller. I dont want the variables to be included in the search if they are empty

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Models.Clients>> GetAllClients(string client_type = "",
    string company_type = "", string sales_agent = "", string country = "")
{
    var result = await GetClients();
    if (client_type.Length > 0 || company_type.Length > 0 || sales_agent.Length > 0 || 
        country.Length > 0)
    {
        // Here I want to exclude the variables from the search if they are = ""
        var s = result
            .Where(item => client_type?.ToString() == item.client_type?.ToString() &&
                           company_type?.ToString() == item.company_type?.ToString());

        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

The question is basically how I can exclude the variables from the search if they are empty.

Comment: Yes thank you. But the real issue is that I'm trying to only return data from that matches the search and are not empty / ""

Answer (score 3):

You can construct the query by applying the Where-clause several times.

```
IEnumerable<Models.Clients> result = await GetClients();

if(client_type.Length > 0) {
    result = result.Where(c => c.client_type.ToString() == client_type);
}
if(company_type.Length > 0) {
    result = result.Where(c => c.company_type.ToString() == company_type);
}
if(sales_agent.Length > 0) {
    result = result.Where(c => c.sales_agent.ToString() == sales_agent);
}
if(country.Length > 0) {
    result = result.Where(c => c.country.ToString() == country);
}
return result;
```

If you apply this approach when querying a database through an O/R-mapper (e.g. EF or EF Core), then the Where-clauses will be translated to comparisons joined by AND in SQL. If you are querying objects, you can also combine the parts with `&&` instead as in:

```
pattern1.Length == 0 || c.prop1 == pattern1 &&
pattern2.Length == 0 || c.prop2 == pattern2 &&
...
```

Also, I am not sure what the type of the properties in the `Models.Clients` is. If they are strings, then you can drop the `.ToString()` calls. You can drop it anyway for the string parameters, as they are strings already.

If the types are not strings, the question is, why you are not using the same types or a nullable version of them as parameters? If this is a user input from a TextBox, this is okay, but otherwise, consider using the same type and drop all of the `.ToString()` calls.

If you are sticking to string: Are you sure that the stringa are never `null`? If they can be `null`, rather use `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(theString)` as @Kit suggests.

Comment: This has the benefit of being very clear in intent. A single `Where` may perform well, but wouldn't read well. Only addition might be to protect against null with e.g. `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(client_type))`.

Comment: Good solution, [I see](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210314/52498) it's very similar to your answer there :)